# How manage error handling in Controller/Repository and show errors in View in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, error-handling

I have created the Asp.Net Core MVC application.

I would like to create for example form for updating the user and catch some specific exceptions and show them in form.

I want to catch two types of exceptions/errors:

1) Form validation

2) Repository exceptions

I have following code:

**UserRepository**

```
public async Task<UserDTO> UpdateUserAsync(UserDTO user)
        {
            var userIdentity = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id.ToString());

            if (userIdentity == null) throw new UserFriendlyException("User does not exist");

            userIdentity.MapTo(user);

            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(userIdentity);

            var userDto = userIdentity.ToModel();

            return userDto;
        }
```

**User Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> User(UserDTO user)
        {
            //Model is not valid
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(user);
            }

            try
            {
                await _identityRepository.UpdateUserAsync(user);
            }
            catch (UserFriendlyException e)
            {
                //Some error from repository
                ModelState.AddModelError(e.Message, e.Message);

                return View(user);
            }

            //OK redirect to list of users
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Users));
        }
```

**UserFriendlyException**

```
public class UserFriendlyException : Exception
    {

        public UserFriendlyException()
        {

        }

        public UserFriendlyException(string message) : base(message)
        {

        }
    }
```

**In View**

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
```

**UserDTO**

```
public class UserDTO
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }

        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }

        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

        public string AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

        public string LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    }
```

Is it good way handle error/exception like above? What is best practise for things like that - some better pattern for it?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a pattern for this?